# How to share different objects between some classes

Tags: c++, templates

what is the best way to share **different objects** between some classes in a generic manner?

For example class A can store an object o with a string as a key in a register and class B can access it using the key.

My first idea was to create a register (singleton) which has a hashtable as a member using a string as the key and a void pointer as the value. But there must be a better solution for this?

Comment: "generic manner" - templates? `void*` is the C solution.

Comment: @MSalters: exactly. Thats why I requested your help.

Comment: At the very least, use `boost::any` instead of `void*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your clarification:

```
template <typename OB>
class A {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, OB> hash;
public:
  OB const& get(std::string const&) const;
  void add(OB const& object, std::string const&);
};
```

That is to say, `A<int>` is a class that stores `int` objects by name, and `A<std::set<float>>` is a class that stores sets of floats by name. You can't mix them. That's in line with the basic C++ philosophy: the type of `theA.get("foo")` is determined at compile time, not by what you put in at runtime.

In C++, you can however "mix" multiple derived types, if you'd need this for your particular case. That's a bit more complicated:

```
template <typename Base>
class A {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Base>> hash;
public:
  Base const& get(std::string const&) const;
  template<typename Derived> void add(std::string const& name, Derived const& object)
  {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> copy(new Derived(object));
    hash.emplace(std::make_pair(name, std::move(copy)));
  }
};
```

There's some slight trickery here as `hash` should be the only owner of the copy, but it's constructed outside and therefore needs to be moved it. (For extra-fancy, I could add a `Derived&&` overload that eliminates that copy too)

Comment: That goes in the right direction and already helped me a little - Thanks! Could you also demonstrate your second approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that all the classes that you must register have a common supertype. 
For instance, if you have to store instances of classes `One`, `Two`, and `Three` you could define a (possibly empty) class `Object` from which your class can derive:

```
class Object {} 
class One : public Object { /* One's member and methods */ }
class Two : public Object { /* Two's member and methods */ }
class Three : public Object { /* Three's member and methods */ }
```

If you follow [MSalters question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976312/148481) you can then declare a `A<Object*>`.

If you cannot have one supertype (for instance because you cannot change `One`, `Two` or `Three`) you may look at [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/variant.html). Again, you can declare a `A<boost::variant<One, Two, Three> >`.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is: how does `B` know the type of the stored object,
and what it can do with it?  Perhaps the simplest solution is just to
have one registry per type.  Alternatively, something like
`boost::variant` can be used, or you can ensure that all types derive
from a common base, and store a pointer to that.  Unless you actually
need to support polymorphism (e.g. operating on an object without
knowing its exact type), I'd avoid the pointer solution, however.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a `shared_ptr`, instead of a naked pointer. If you have a C++11 compliant compiler, `shared_ptr` is in the `std` namespace. Otherwise, use the Boost implementation.

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question correctly. Are you in fact asking how to store objects of different types in the same container?